# Replacing NgRoute with UI router not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hey I'm trying to replace ngroute with ui-router in my website but when I migrated the view is not inserted.  Here's the app.js snippet:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngDialog', 'ui-router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
//testing to see if this works
$stateProvider
  .state('browse', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/browse',
    controller: 'browseController'
  });
}]);
```

The browse file is an ejs file, and I've tried calling it directly using the file path (views/browse.ejs) but that doesn't work.  /browse accesses templates through the browser.

Comment: Did you switch from the ng-view to the ui-view directive in your markup?

Comment: also remove ng-route from modules it is not being used now.

Comment: Yep I did switch to ui-view

Comment: templete url should end with .html extension